# Another Magento 1.9.1 Cron-E-Mail-Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, email-scheduler

There have been different threads upon similar issues, that sorrily couldn’t help me further.The situation:

- Magento 1.9.1 isn’t processing sales e-mails, although I arranged crontab to be executed every 5 minutes via SSH
- E-Mails are not sent out, table `cron_schedule` is empty, table `core_email_queue` is filled, but field processed_at is empty
- To the E-Mail address I deposited I get an error-email every 5 minutes with this content: `/direct/path/to/the/store/cron.sh: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file`
- Line 29 in cron.sh is an empty line

Has anyone similar experiences or an idea how to fix this issue? Any hint is highly appreciated.

I originally developed the shop under Windows on a local xampp-environment and then transferred it to a linux-hosting environment. Everything works fine, it is currently running on a test-URL under live conditions.
I set up crontab like this:

MAILTO=info@mywebsite.com
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /direct/path/to/the/shob/cron.sh

This is the content of cron.sh, the last line being empty:

```
#!/bin/sh
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
    MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

Comment: set cron to cron.php file

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the EOF character like this:

```
dos2unix file.sh
```

Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366607/1016425.

Also notice that some characters need to be escaped, for instance "%" like this "\%"

Comment: Thanks for this proposal. But but by entering

dos2unix cron.sh

the issue was not solved. After that even the error-message hasn't been sent :-(.

Comment: Could you show us the content of cron.sh also which OS are you using? How did you set up the crontab?

Comment: I placed this information in the question block above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: After a lot of research I found out that it is a specific server issue. For all customers of 1and1 shared hosting some tipps, which gets the cron-job running in the above mentioned setting:
- Set rights 755 for cron.sh and cron.php on the server
- Explicitly replace within cron.sh
PHP_BIN=`which php` by PHP_BIN='/usr/local/bin/php5.5', if the installed php-version is 5.5, also set the right single quotation marks
- */5 * * * * /bin/sh /direct/path/to/the/shop/cron.sh &> /dev/null
is the right command to avoid error messages
With these settings the problem was solved.